# How do I make an HTML text box show a hint when empty?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the search box on my web page to display the word "Search" in gray italics. When the box receives focus, it should look just like an empty text box. If there is already text in it, it should display the text normally (black, non-italics). This will help me avoid clutter by removing the label.

BTW, this is an on-page [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) search, so it has no button.

Comment: since the question was asked HTML5  placeholder attribute has become supported by all browsers.

Comment: Hi Michael.  Would you be willing to change the accepted answer on this page?  There looks to be an clear winner, which is different to the accepted answer.

Comment: The problem with a JavaScript solution is that not everyone has JavaScript turned on.  The placeholder doesn't disappear when the textbox gets focus if using a browser plug-in such as NoScript (very handy for developers to have installed).  The Placeholder option is the most robust solution.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

Another option, if you're happy to have this feature only for newer browsers, is to use the support offered by HTML 5's **placeholder** attribute:

```
<input name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
```

In the absence of any styles, in Chrome this looks like:

[image]

You can try demos out [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/examples/input-placeholder.html) and in *[HTML5 Placeholder Styling with CSS](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css)*.

Be sure to check the [browser compatibility of this feature](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder). Support in Firefox was added in 3.7. Chrome is fine. Internet Explorer only added support in 10. If you target a browser that does not support input placeholders, you can use a jQuery plugin called [jQuery HTML5 Placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder), and then just add the following JavaScript code to enable it.

```
$('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();
```

Comment: @Duke, it works in Fx3.7+, (Safari / Chrome) and Opera. IE9 doesn't support it, so I guess IE8 doesn't either.

Comment: Yes I just found out today that FF3.6 doesn't support it.

Comment: I think it's moved again. I found it here: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: Caveat developer "Internet Explorer 10 and 11 do not show the placeholder when the field is focused, even if the field is empty."

Answer (score 92):

That is known as a textbox watermark, and it is done via JavaScript.

- http://naspinski.net/post/Text-Input-Watermarks-using-Javascript-(IE-Compatible).aspx

or if you use jQuery, a much better approach:

- http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/
- or [code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark)

Comment: That second link is broken. This might be similar: http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/

Comment: Found another jQuery approach. this project is hosted @ http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Comment: The digitalbrush plugin will save the 'watermark' to the database.  It is in beta, and has not been updated since 2007.  I recommend instead using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/ as @JP suggested.

Comment: i think the author of the question should go back and mark @JP comment as the best answer.

Comment: The jQuery watermark plugin is pretty noob because it doesn't handle the case where the input is the same as the pre-filled value. In that case, it makes your input text grey again!

Comment: @Jasie - I don't think many people will enter 'enter text' or something like that, and if they do, it would be easy to catch it if you were actually worried about it...?

Comment: I guess, but then you'd have to write code on top of a plugin that's supposed to help you not write code :)

Comment: @Jasie: it mentions that in it's readme - easy fix is to just add a bunch of spaces to the end of the watermark text

Comment: Also, the digitalbush plugin does not handle password inputs. It shows ****** instead of Password

Comment: the modern way to do this is use the html5 placeholder attribute, no javascript is needed at all.

Answer (score 42):

You can set the **placeholder** using the [`placeholder` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) in HTML ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder)). The `font-style` and `color` can be [changed with CSS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/) (although browser support is limited).

```css
input[type=search]::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Safari, Chrome(, Opera?) */
 color:gray;
 font-style:italic;
}
input[type=search]:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
 color:gray;
 font-style:italic;
}
input[type=search]::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
 color:gray;
 font-style:italic;
}
input[type=search]:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE (10+?) */
 color:gray;
 font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Search" type="search" name="q">
```

Comment: Was looking for this, ta - further info http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#placeholder

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer.  The placeholder attribute may not have been widely supported when this was originally posted in 2010, but now it's supported by all current browsers except IE8.

Answer (score 20):

You can add and remove a special CSS class and modify the input value `onfocus`/`onblur` with JavaScript:

```
<input type="text" class="hint" value="Search..."
    onfocus="if (this.className=='hint') { this.className = ''; this.value = ''; }"
    onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.className = 'hint'; this.value = 'Search...'; }">
```

Then specify a **hint** class with the styling you want in your CSS for example:

```
input.hint {
    color: grey;
}
```

Comment: I've posted an answer that does the same thing but in a more convenient and maintainable way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108207/how-do-i-make-an-html-text-box-show-a-hint-when-empty/2994702#2994702

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to wire up your JavaScript events using some kind of JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) or [YUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library) and put your code in an external .js-file.

But if you want a quick-and-dirty solution this is your inline HTML-solution:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="Search"
    onclick="if(this.value=='Search'){this.value=''; this.style.color='#000'}" 
    onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Search'; this.style.color='#555'}" />
```

**Updated**: Added the requested coloring-stuff.

Comment: This is OK for searches, but in many cases you don't want watermarks to be submitted on any submit event.

Comment: @k.robinson I +1 that statement. This was the quickest and most compact code at that moment. It could be solved more fine-grained with a javascript code-block.

Answer (score 4):

I posted [a solution for this on my website](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/javascript/hintTextbox.html) some time ago.  To use it, import a single `.js` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/hint-textbox.js"></script>
```

Then annotate whatever inputs you want to have hints with the CSS class `hintTextbox`:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="enter email" class="hintTextbox" />
```

More information and example are available [here](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/javascript/hintTextbox.html).

Comment: But it is broken. If I input the same text that was the hint, it behaves as if no input was given (if I tab into and then out of it again)

Comment: @Stephan: Yes that's the only caveat I know of.  Have you actually found that to be an issue in practice?  If so then you might have to investigate layering a div above and displaying/hiding it. This is the simplest solution I know of.  I also degrades nicely if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: I was triggered by the setting of the value. I have a combined need of pre-filling with an existing or default value and a hint when the text box is empty

Comment: @Stephan - I've actually come across a need for this today and am looking at jQuery plugins.  The one linked to in the accepted answer suffers the same problem mine does.  Do you know of an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a functional example with Google Ajax library cache and some jQuery magic.

This would be the CSS:

```
<style type="text/stylesheet" media="screen">
    .inputblank { color:gray; }  /* Class to use for blank input */
</style>
```

This would would be the JavaScript code:

```
<script language="javascript"
        type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script>
    // Load jQuery
    google.load("jquery", "1");

    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        $("#search_form")
            .submit(function() {
                alert("Submitted. Value= " + $("input:first").val());
                return false;
        });

        $("#keywords")
            .focus(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == 'Search') {
                    $(this)
                    .removeClass('inputblank')
                    .val('');
                }
            })
            .blur(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(this)
                    .addClass('inputblank')
                    .val('Search');
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

And this would be the HTML:

```
<form id="search_form">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Search the site</legend>
            <label for="keywords">Keywords:</label>
        <input id="keywords" type="text" class="inputblank" value="Search"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I hope it's enough to make you interested in both the GAJAXLibs and in jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Now it become very easy.
In html we can give the **placeholder** attribute for *input* elements.

**e.g.**

```
<input type="text" name="fst_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
```

check for more details :http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery users: naspinski's jQuery link seems broken, but try this one:
http://remysharp.com/2007/01/25/jquery-tutorial-text-box-hints/

You get a free jQuery plugin tutorial as a bonus. :)

Comment: I use Remy's plugin at http://www.tripfootprint.com/ and it works great; I love that it's simple enough to follow along and grok.

Answer (score 2):

This is called "watermark".

I found the jQuery plugin *[jQuery watermark](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-watermark)* which, unlike the first answer, does not require extra setup (the original answer also needs a special call to before the form is submitted).

Answer (score 2):

I found the jQuery plugin *[jQuery Watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/)* to be better than the one listed in the top answer. Why better? Because it supports password input fields. Also, setting the color of the watermark (or other attributes) is as easy as creating a `.watermark` reference in your CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery Form Notifier](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formnotifier/) - it is one of the most popular jQuery plugins and doesn't suffer from the bugs some of the other jQuery suggestions here do (for example, you can freely style the watermark, without worrying if it will get saved to the database).

jQuery Watermark uses a single CSS style directly on the form elements (I noticed that CSS font-size properties applied to the watermark also affected the text boxes -- not what I wanted). The plus with jQuery Watermark is you can drag-drop text into fields (jQuery Form Notifier doesn't allow this).

Another one suggested by some others (the one at digitalbrush.com), will accidentally submit the watermark value to your form, so I strongly recommend against it.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily have a box read "Search" then when the focus is changed to it have the text be removed.  Something like this:

`<input onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" value="Search" />`

Of course if you do that the user's own text will disappear when they click.  So you probably want to use something more robust:

```
<input name="keyword_" type="text" size="25"  style="color:#999;" maxlength="128" id="keyword_"
onblur="this.value = this.value || this.defaultValue; this.style.color = '#999';"
onfocus="this.value=''; this.style.color = '#000';"
value="Search Term">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a background image to render the text:

```
 input.foo { }
 input.fooempty { background-image: url("blah.png"); }
```

Then all you have to do is detect `value == 0` and apply the right class:

```
 <input class="foo fooempty" value="" type="text" name="bar" />
```

And the jQuery JavaScript code looks like this:

```
jQuery(function($)
{
    var target = $("input.foo");
    target.bind("change", function()
    {
        if( target.val().length > 1 )
        {
            target.addClass("fooempty");
        }
        else
        {
            target.removeClass("fooempty");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

---

You can use a attribute called `placeholder=""`
Here's a demo:

```
<html>
<body>
// try this out!
<input placeholder="This is my placeholder"/>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign something like this to onfocus:

```
if (this.value == this.defaultValue)
    this.value = ''
this.className = ''
```

and this to onblur:

```
if (this.value == '')
    this.value = this.defaultValue
this.className = 'placeholder'
```

(You can use something a bit cleverer, like a framework function, to do the classname switching if you want.)

With some CSS like this:

```
input.placeholder{
    color: gray;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page first loads, have Search appear in the text box, colored gray if you want it to be.

When the input box receives focus, select all of the text in the search box so that the user can just start typing, which will delete the selected text in the process. This will also work nicely if the user wants to use the search box a second time since they won't have to manually highlight the previous text to delete it.

```
<input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="this.select();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution of "Knowledge Chikuse" - simple and clear. Only need to add a call to blur when the page load is ready which will set the initial state:

```
$('input[value="text"]').blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a simple, one line javascript solution which works great. Here is an example both for textbox and for textarea:

```
    <textarea onfocus="if (this.value == 'Text') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'Text'; }">Text</textarea>

    <input type="text" value="Text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Text') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'Text'; }">
```

only "downside" is to validate at $_POST or in Javascript validation before doing anything with the value of the field. Meaning, checking that the field's value isn't "Text".

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input[value="text"]').focus(function(){ 
if ($(this).attr('class')=='hint') 
{ 
   $(this).removeClass('hint'); 
   $(this).val(''); 
}
});

$('input[value="text"]').blur(function(){
  if($(this).val() == '')
  {
    $(this).addClass('hint');
    $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
  } 
});

<input type="text" value="" title="Default Watermark Text">
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple Html 'required' tag is useful.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" required>
<input type="submit" value="enter">
</form>
```

It specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form or press the button submit.
[Here is example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required)

Comment: While it is useful, it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score -3):

User AJAXToolkit from http://asp.net