# jQuery Watermarked input and validation

Tags: jquery, validation, watermark

On a HTML page I have an inputbox that has a 'watermark' on it when it is empty. (eg: "enter text here..."). Kind of like this: http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/ - but custom written.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to validate this field with the jQuery validation plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/) so that it treats my watermark text as if the field was empty.

I can't find an option in the jQuery validator to let me specify a custom rule for when a field is valid, is there one? I could find options that allow me to specify whether a field *needs* to be validated based on custom logic, but not how it should be validated.

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make an HTML text box show a hint when empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108207/how-do-i-make-an-html-text-box-show-a-hint-when-empty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this blog post:

http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2008/10/starting-with-jquery-how-to-write.html

Tells you how to construct a custom validation rule for a field.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out a solution based on your link.

Comment: Just noticed the answer.  Thanks for posting the link and finding it useful!

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Kazar for providing me with the link, I came up with the following solution (if anyone is interested):

```
    function notWatermark(value, element){
        return value != 'enter text...';
    }

    $.validator.addMethod("notWatermark", notWatermark, "Field cannot be empty.");

    $('#SearchForm').validate({
        rules: {
            SomeField: {
                required: true,
                notWatermark: true
            }
         },
```

Comment: Just a point - if someone types 'enter text...' into the box, what happens? Perhaps better to have a flag using the class of the element?

Comment: Your point is correct, but I'm not worried about someone entering enter text... in the textbox. I like the side effect of it not being allowed. :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the Watermark plugin for jQuery, but my situation was similar:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

It uses a classname for the display of the watermark.  (I'm not sure if the DigitalBrush version uses a class or not.) I've modified the above function to use jQuery's hasClass() function to determine whether or not the field is evaluated as "empty" based on currently assigned classes.

```
function notWatermark(value, element){
 return !$(element).hasClass("waterMarkClass");
}
$.validator.addMethod("notWatermark", notWatermark, "Required.");
```

Answer (score 1):

When using unique watermark labels for each of your testboxes (For example 'enter firstname', 'enter last name'...), you could improve the script to:

```
function noWatermark(value, element) {
        return value.toLowerCase() != element.defaultValue.toLowerCase();
    }

$.validator.addMethod("noWatermark", noWatermark, "required.");
```

This also removes the hardcoded text from your script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the validation plugin works, but this is a separate module that is usable.

```
   var SetWatermark = function( oElemToWatermark, sWatermark )
   {
      var CheckFocus = function(oEvent)
      {
         var oElem = $(this);

         if ( oElem.val() == oElem.data("Watermark") )
            oElem.val("").css("color", "");
      }

      var CheckBlur = function(oEvent)
      {
         var oElem = $(this);

         if ( oElem.val().length == 0 )
            oElem.val( oElem.data("Watermark") ).css("color", "Grey");
      }

      // HTML5 (simple route)
      if ( oElemToWatermark[0].placeholder != undefined )
         oElemToWatermark[0].placeholder = sWatermark;

      // pre HTML5 (manual route)
      else if (oElemToWatermark.data("Watermark") == undefined)
         oElemToWatermark  .data("Watermark", sWatermark)
                           .val(sWatermark)
                           .on("focus", CheckFocus )
                           .on("blur",  CheckBlur  );
   }

   var GetWatermarkText = function(oElem)
   {
      if (oElem[0].plaeholder != undefined)
         return oElem[0].placeholder;
      else if ( oElem.data("Watermark") != undefined )
         return oElem.data("Watermark");
      else
      { 
         alert("The element " + oElem[0].id + " does not have a Watermark value.");
         return "";
      }
   }

   var GetWatermarkValue = function(oElem)
   {
      var sVal       = oElem.val();
      var sWatermark = oElem.data("Watermark");

      if (oElem[0].placeholder   != undefined 
      ||  sWatermark             == undefined 
      ||  sWatermark             != sVal)
         return sVal;
      else if (sVal == sWatermark)
         return "";
   }
```