# TextBox with Default value

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I want to use a textbox that shows a text.

For example : Someone@example.com. When the user clicks on it, the textbox is cleared and ready for the user to type.

[image: sample textbox]

Answer (score 6):

If you are working on newer browsers then you can use `placeholder` property which is new in HTML 5

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Someone@exmaple.com"></asp:TextBox>
```

otherwise you can also use `onfocus` and `onblur` event to do this as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911301/javascript-watermarks-for-textboxes)

Answer (score 2):

you can use this, is so easy

```
 <input class="status" type="text" size="5" placeholder="started"  />
```

placeholder show you the text you want

hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Add textbox to your webpage.
2. Set the default text in the obj.Text property.
3. Add properties ( focus & blur events).
4. On focus event, check if the value = Someone@exmaple.com , then empty the text box.
5. On blur, check if the textbox is empty, then set the text : Someone@exmaple.com

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
<TextBox ID="txtone" runat="server" tooltip="Enter comments"
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Someone@exmaple.com';"
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Someone@exmaple.com') this.value='';"
Text="Someone@exmaple.com"></TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a server control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Someone@exmaple.com"></asp:TextBox>
```

For an HTML control:

```
<input Type="Text" ID="textBox1"  placeholder="Someone@exmaple.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ajax if you want a cross browser compatible version.

```
<ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="EmailClear" runat="server" TargetControlID="EmailAddress" WatermarkText="Someone@example.com" />
```

You just have to add this under each field.