# How to write something in textbox until user clicks it

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I wanna have a the text "Username" in the username-Textbox in gray until the user clicks it. When he enters something the box should be empty auhtomaticly and black color again.

How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input placeholders for Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164/input-placeholders-for-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modern browsers which support css3 like chrome allows a placeholder attribute to the input elements. Example:

```
<input name="username" placeholder="User name" />
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Alternative is to use javascript onfocus/onblur to show/delete the placeholder text inside textbox

Answer (score 1):

You should check asp.net ajax watermark extender for cross browser compatibility:

[Link](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)

First you need to include ajaxToolkit, then you can use it like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TBWE2" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="**YouTextBoxID**"
    WatermarkText="Type First Name Here"
    WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As @rajesh mentioned, you can use `placeholder` attribute in modern browsers.

For older browsers, search for "html textbox watermark". [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911301/javascript-watermarks-for-textboxes) some good javascript solutions,