# jQuery Watermark and using .Val()

Tags: jquery, if-statement, watermark

I have a problem in that I am using a simple watermark plugin such that it works

```
jQuery('#selector').Watermark('Watermark text here ...');
```

The problem is - when I try and use something like

```
if (jQuery('#selector').val() != "") { //do stuff }
```

The statement is `True` because of the watermark. Is there anyway I can somehow "ignore" this watermark value for my `If` statement ?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16471949/1257652

Answer (score 3):

```
if (jQuery('#selector').val() != "" && jQuery('#selector').val() != "'Watermark text here ...'") { //do stuff }
```

This only assumes that the watermark text is static across examples. If not then you may need a collection of watermark texts?

Answer (score 1):

You could ignore the watermark text as well other than empty:

```
if (jQuery('#selector').val() != "" && jQuery('#selector').val() != "your watermark text")
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: hmm yeah thanks sarfraz - this is exactly what I'd thought of myself. Just wondering whether there was something I was completely missing here :) +1 for this

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here:

[Jquery: Is there some way to make val() return an empty string instead of 'undefined' for an empty list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495370/jquery-is-there-some-way-to-make-val-return-an-empty-string-instead-of-undefi)

The gist of the solution in your case would be:

```
if ((jQuery('#selector').not('.watermark').val()||'') != "") { //do stuff }
```