# Jquery: Is there some way to make val() return an empty string instead of 'undefined' for an empty list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With Jquery, is there some way to make val() return an empty string instead of 'undefined' when called against an empty list of elements?

E.g., I have this code:

```
var x = $('#my-textbox-id').not('.watermark').val();
```

The idea is that I want to get the value of my textbox, but I want an empty string if it is currently showing the watermark (i don't want the watermark value!).

The selector works, but i don't want 'undefined' - I want an empty string ''.

Comment: var x = $('#my-textbox-id').not('.watermark').val() || '';

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write `(...).val() || ""`.

Only use this for text fields; it will also replace `false` or the number `0` with `""`.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `$.trim` to get the expected result.

*Example:* `$.trim($('#my-textbox-id').not('.watermark').val())`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var x = $('#my-textbox-id').hasClass("watermark") ? "" : $('#my-textbox-id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $('#my-textbox-id').not('.watermark').val() == undefined 
? '' 
: $('#my-textbox-id').not('.watermark').val();
```