# looking for a script for textbox watermark

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a javascript that makes the text inside the textbox to disappear once the mouse is inside the textbox and reappears on default.. it has to be a javascript...

Comment: Are you using any framework, JQuery, Prototype, etc?

Comment: You have similar question posted and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108207/how-do-i-make-an-html-text-box-show-a-hint-when-empty cheers

Comment: the work is nothing as such... its a simple php work and i am looking for some easy javascript..

Comment: The title stinks, should be edited so it is useful to people performing searches in the future.

Comment: @epascarello.. hope this is better..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  function clearGhost(id,text) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if (obj && obj.value == text) obj.value = '';
  }

  function Ghost(id,text) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if (obj && obj.value == '') obj.value = text;
  }
</script>

<input type=text name=myText id=myText size=20 value="Ghost Text"
    onfocus="clearGhost('myText','Ghost Text');" onblur="Ghost('myText','Ghost Text');">
```

This is untested... would definitely be easier with jQuery.

Comment: you want it to go away when they CLICK right? not just mouse over... if you wanted it to go away on hover just add onmouseover="clearGhost('myText','Ghost Text');" and onmouseout="Ghost('myText','Ghost Text');" to have it come back.

Comment: .. it really works buddy.. thats so simple to work on???? thanks a lot.. may be  i got screwed with some ids previously...

Comment: You really like a solution that requires you to put the default text in 3 places when the browser has a property that gives you it to you. Seems like a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Newer browsers do this without JavaScript with the `placeholder`attribute: 
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="text" value="mm/dd/yyyy" id="date1"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function(){

            function showHideDefaultText(elem){

                var defaultValue = elem.defaultValue;

                var showDefaultText = function(){ 
                    if(this.value.length === 0){
                        this.value = defaultValue;
                    }
                }

                var hideDefaultText = function(){ 
                    if(this.value===defaultValue){  
                        this.value = "";
                    }
                }

                elem.onfocus = hideDefaultText;
                elem.onblur = showDefaultText;

            }

            var d1 = document.getElementById("date1");
            showHideDefaultText(d1);

        })()

    </script>
```