# Question on button, javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a form using HTML codes. I would like to do something like... prompting the user to type something into the form. For example, before I actually typed something in this box, the title actually prompted for:"*What's your programming question? Be specific.*". I would like to do something like this, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Where do you want the text displayed? Is it in the text box that you want them to type their question, or is it just text on the page?

Comment: I would like the text to be displayed IN the text box where user can type in their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108207/how-do-i-make-an-html-text-box-show-a-hint-when-empty) on SO, it talks all about using a input textbox and watermarks.

Comment: Oh yes, I got it! Thanks =) It's placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about watermarks on your input fields. If you are using jQuery you should have a look at this page: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/