# If input field has no value, add a new value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Using JavaScript I'm trying to put together some validation for my form. What I'm trying to achieve is that if one input field is left blank, then a value is automatically added to that field upon hitting submit.

I will start off by saying I attempted by using the answer from this question: [If input value is blank, assign a value of “empty” with Javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752714/if-input-value-is-blank-assign-a-value-of-empty-with-javascript)

However, this did not work.

I then tried to use the following in my external `.JS` file:

```
validateForm();
function validateForm() {
    "use strict";
//POSITION VALIDATION
    var numberOf = document.forms.themainform.numberOf.value;
    if (numberOf === "") {
        numberOf.value = "-5";
    }
}
```

and I also attempted to use a variation of the other questions answer:

```
var numberOf = document.forms.themainform.getElementById('numberOf');

if(numberOf.value.length === 0) {
    numberOf.value = "-5";
}
```

But as before, no luck. Below is the code to my HTML form:

```
<script>validateForm();</script>
<form action="" method="post" name="themainform" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<table>
<tr><td>Number Of</td>
<td><input type="text" name="numberOf" id="numberOf" size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="themainform" value="submit"/>
<hr/>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what display `console.log(numberOf);` ?

Comment: since id should be different among the whole page I would wrote something like : `numberOf = document.getElementById('numberOf') || defaultNumberOf;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `validateForm()` after the form is rendered so the html file should look like this

```
<form action="" method="post" name="themainform" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Number Of</td>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="numberOf" id="numberOf" size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="themainform" value="submit"/>
    <table/>
</form>
<script>validateForm();</script>
```

and in you js file, you can't set `numberOf.value = "-5";` since numberOf is just a string, it should be the dom elment.

```
function validateForm() {
    "use strict";
//POSITION VALIDATION
    var numberOf = document.forms.themainform.numberOf;
    if (numberOf.value === "") {
        numberOf.value = "-5";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, although I managed to figure it out using a different method, I tested your method and it worked perfectly also. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance everyone. But I managed to figure it out :) However, I also tested Anthony's method and it also worked, so accepted his answer.

I used:

```
if(document.forms.themainform.numberOf.value === "") {
    document.forms.themainform.numberOf.value = "-5";
}
```

This meant that if someone left this input field empty, on submit it would put -5 as the input.