# disappearing form hits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

i dont know even how this is name. If i add here new question then i title is disappearing hits. I can add default value in input, but this isnt this. Here is another. How can i make this?
And how can i make this in input password? There is *****, so how can i write in clean text?
Generally what this is name?

Thanks for help!

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name" /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Last Name" /> <br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" value="password" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<input type="password" name="pwd" value="password" placeholder="Enter password" />
```

However it will only work in some browsers.
So if you want to support the majority, you'll need some js to pre-fill it. Google 'html input hint' or 'placeholder'. There are js plugins for this out there.

Here's a related stackoverflow thread:
[How do I make an HTML text box show a hint when empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108207/how-do-i-make-an-html-text-box-show-a-hint-when-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder attribue ;)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="default text" />
<input type="password" placeholder="default text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a combination of the `placeholder` attribute and feature detection so you know whether the browser supports it, and falling back on JavaScript code if it doesn't.

So your markup would be:

```
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" />
```

...and it'll get handled by browsers that support it, ignored by ones that don't.

The feature detection is easy:

```
var text = document.getElementById("yourfieldid");
if ("placeholder" in text) {
    // The browser supports placeholders, your markup should be sufficient
}
else {
    // Browser doesn't, need to do something with JavaScript
}
```

I've written [a jQuery plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/place5/) that does this.